# Exclude original message from reply in Outlook 365 web app

Tags: outlook-365

I know there are options to do this in Outlook desktop, but I can't find an option in Office 365 online. I basically just want to reply to messages without quoting the original message in my reply.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it is not an option in Outlook.com or the beta version.

However, Office 365 has more functionality, so it may be available there.  So I have some suggestions ...

Places to look in Settings (beta version):

- Messaging
- Compose and Reply

Places to look in Options (regular version):

- Message Options
- Reply Settings
- Forwarding (some older versions of Outlook had it there for some reason)
- Email Signature
- Message Format